# Update the record of one table based on the update on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-update, subquery

I have two table one tblstationerystock (stationery_name,stationery_code, balance) and other tblstationerytranscation(stationery_code,trsntype,quantity).Trsntype column is transction type consists of two type of value (received or issued)

I want to calculate the value of balance in first table based on any transcation for stationery in second table.my table looks like this

[image: Clickk here for table]

I dont have much knowledge about sql .Is it possiblePlease guide me to achieve this .

Comment: this already exists in dba https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278612/calculating-the-record-value

Comment: Please refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262292/how-do-i-handle-duplicates-when-they-are-asked-on-other-se-sites

Answer (score 0):

One option is an update/join query:

```
update tblstationerystock s
inner join (
    select stationery_code, 
        sum(case when trsntype = 'RECEIVED' then quantity else -quantity end) balance
    from tblstationerytranscation
    group by stationery_code
) t on t.stationery_code = s.stationery_code
set s.balance = t.balance
```

From design perspective, storing such information is not a good thing, because it is hard to keep it up to date; you might soon find yourself in need for a trigger, that automatically updates the master table whenever a transaction is inserted, modified or deleted in the other table. This is derived information, that can be computed on the fly whenever needed. For this, you can, for example, create a view:

```
create view w_tblstationerystock as
select s.stationery_name, s.stationery_code 
    (
        select sum(case when trsntype = 'RECEIVED' then quantityu else -quantity end) balance
        from tblstationerytranscation t
        where t.stationery_code = s.stationery_code
    ) as balance
from tblstationerystock s
```

You can then run your queries directly against the view, which provides an always up-to-date perspective at your data.

Comment: where should i run this query on first table or second table

Comment: @hellow: this query updates the `balance` in the `tblstationerystock` table from the `tblstationerytranscation` table - which is how I understood your question. But see my updated answer for additional thoughts on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: update tblstationerystock 
inner join (
    select sum(case when txntype = 'RECEIVED' then quantity else -quantity end) balance
    from tblstationerytranscation
    group by stationery_code
)  on tblstationerytranscation.stationery_code = tblstationerystock.stationery_code
set tblstationerystock.balance = tblstationerytranscation.balance

Comment: i used above query but it shows error --You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'on tblstationerytranscation.stationery_code = tblstationerystock.stationery_code'

Comment: @hellow: this is not the query I provided you with. Please run the query exactly as given, and report if it works or not.

Comment: Unknown column 't.stationery_code' in 'on clause' this is thee error

Comment: @hellow: ah yes, that is correct. Fixed.

Comment: It is  working  can you tell me how to run this query automaticallyy whenever any update in the second table

Comment: @hellow: this is what the rest of my answer discusses. I would not recommend storing that information. Keeping it up to date is tedious. You can use the view instead, as suggested.